# How to internally call an overriden method using the Revealing Prototype Pattern

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming, revealing-prototype

I'm currently struggling with some concepts and syntax for the Revealing Prototype Pattern in Javascript. Could you guys help me understand it?

What I am trying to achieve: call an overridden method from another method of the base class.

How I did it:

1. Base class:

   ```
   var Base = function() {
       //...
   };
   Base.prototype = function() {
       var init = function() {
           console.log('init');
           customInit.call(this);
       },
       customInit = function() {
           console.log('custom init source');
       };

       return {
           init: init,
           customInit: customInit
       };
   } ();
   ```
2. Extended class:

   ```
   var Extended = function () {
       //...
   };
   Extended.prototype = new Base();
   Extended.prototype.customInit = function () {
       console.log('custom init extended');
   };
   ```
3. Call to extended class:

   ```
   window.addEventListener('load', function (){
       var myObject = new Extended();
       myObject.init();
       myObject.customInit();
   });
   ```

The call to `customInit` from outside of the class executes the overriden version of the method (what I want), while the call from within the class still calls the "base" version of the method (not what I want).

Is this normal? Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some modification of your code (1 line):

```
.......
var init = function() {
    console.log('init');
    //customInit.call(this);
    this.customInit.call(this);
},
.....
```

Comment: Just what I was missing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can call a parent function in child with Parents.prototype. some function.call(this, param1, param2)

For more info you can check out this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: Sounds more like the opposite of what I wanted to achieve. Still, super useful information (and link). Thanks a lot.